# Return each year since 2006

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, timestamp, timespan

Using PHP I'm trying to echo each year since 2006 minus the current year; the result would be something like: 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012. I'm needing a foreach loop so I can rap each result in a `<li>`. I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this result.

Comment: Will `for($i=2006; $i<date("Y"); ++$i){echo "<li>$i</li>";}` work?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code you have tried so far and we will give feedback.  We're here to help, not to do your homework for you - try your best and we'll help you get there.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)
and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php)

After that take a look at 
[Negative DateInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350778/negative-dateinterval) (KingCrunch's answer)

IMO this is the cleanest way.