# How to Subtract Minutes

Tags: php

I want to send a reminder email.I don't want to use `cron` on Linux/Unix/BSD box or Scheduled Tasks on Windows.

I'm trying to subtract 15 minutes from the current time.

here is my code so far (doesn't work):

```
$days   = date("j",time());
$months = date("n",time());
$years  = date("Y",time());
$hours  = date("G",time());
$mins   = (date("i",time()));
$secs   = date("s",time());
$mins   = $mins-15;
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Change the date into a timestamp (in seconds) then minus 15 minutes (in seconds) and then convert back to a date:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - (15 * 60);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Answer (score 58):

To subtract 15 minutes from the current time, you can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$newTime = strtotime('-15 minutes');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime);
```

Comment: Strongly advise this solution, much more elegant and expresive.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `DateInterval`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval("PT15M");
$interval->invert = 1;
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format("c") . "\n";
```

Comment: This solution also will be better if you have timezone specified as part of the DateTime object.

Comment: Much more readable creation of the `DateInterval` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351113/878514): `$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-15 minutes');`

Answer (score 27):

you can try this as well,

```
$dateTimeMinutesAgo = new DateTime("15 minutes ago");
$dateTimeMinutesAgo = $dateTimeMinutesAgo->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Extremely straightforward. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

How about substracting the 15 minutes from time() before converting it?

```
$time = time() - (15 * 60);
```

And then use $time instead of time() in your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$before15mins = strtotime('-15 minutes');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $before15mins);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `strtotime` function to subtract days, hours and/or seconds from current time.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Following is the way you can add days / hours / minutes / sec to current time

```
  $addInterval = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+$days days $hours hours $minute minute $sec second", strtotime(currentTime)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use DateInterval object

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('PT10H30S'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>
```

Comment: Maybe add some sort of explanation on what the lines do? For newbies that's not clear

Answer (score 3):

To subtract 15 minutes you can do:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 60 * 15));
```

You can replace 15 with the number of minutes you want.

In case you're looking to subtract seconds you can simply do:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 10));
```

In this way you'll subtract 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$min = time() - 900; //900 seconds = 15 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove 5 minutes to a DateTime, i use :

```
$dateTime->modify("-5 minutes");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only time value than below will be useful

```
// Your time
$time = '12:15:00';

// Returned value '12:00:00'
$newTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($time) - (15*60));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is outdated but i just want to share how i did it in easy way

```
$current = new DateTime("10 minutes ago", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila') );

echo $current->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with DateTime is getting simpler in PHP. These are sample but you can try more

```
$dateTime->modify('-2 minutes');
$dateTime->modify('+2 minutes');
$dateTime->modify('+2 days');
$dateTime->modify('+2 years');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//To Get Current DateTime
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//To Get Current DateTime - 15Min
$oldDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($currentDate) - (15 * 60));

echo $currentDate;
echo $oldDate;
```

Comment: Is there any good reason to duplicate the existing answers? And why don't you use `DateTime` for this, providing a more readable code?