# I want to subtract 30 minutes from a time

Tags: php

Hello My question is simple, Please let me know how i can subtract 30 minutes from a time my code is :

```
$endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $futureDate);


        $d_newdate = strtotime($endDate);
        $d_newdate1 = $d_newdate - ('30 minutes');
        echo $d_newdate2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $d_newdate1);die("workings");
```

This code is adding one hour in time its wrong.i want to subtract 30 minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, subtract minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717911/php-subtract-minutes)

Comment: Man... Just google "how i can subtract 30 minutes from a time my code" and the first entry will take you to @Saty link. Google your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '2015-08-02 15:30:00';
echo $date."<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("-30 minutes",strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-30 minutes'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
$d_newdate = strtotime($endDate);

$d_newdate1 = $d_newdate - (30 * 60);

$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $d_newdate1);
```

Comment: Its working fine for me as I tested before posting here. What problem you are facing? are you getting right value in your variable `$endDate`

Comment: I resolve this .now my new query is how i can retrieve all the records from data base in between two date time my query is :

 SELECT * FROM `appointment` WHERE `ap_datetime` = '2015-09-08 01:30:00' AND (`cur_datetime` BETWEEN '2015-09-08 01:30:00' AND '2015-09-08 02:30:00')