# How can subtract seconds from a time on seconds?

Tags: php, strtotime

From a time like:

```
$time_on_seconds = 18000;
```

It is equal to 5 hours.

Now for subtract seconds Im using this code:

```
$new_time_on_seconds = date("H:i", strtotime($time_on_seconds) - 60);
```

It return me `23:59` when this should return me `4:59`

Comment: Full answer can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717911/how-to-subtract-minutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Subtract Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717911/how-to-subtract-minutes)

Comment: I'd say that does not answer the question since it's completely different. But sure, it gives some hints at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove strtotime.
Strtotime does what the name says it takes a str (string) and makes it time (seconds) so using that on a already number won't work.

```
$time_on_seconds = 18000;
echo $new_time_on_seconds = date("H:i", $time_on_seconds - 60);
```

But keep in mind date() is timezone aware so you may end up with a wrong result depending on your timezone.
Set the timezone to UTC and you should get the correct result.