# Need to remove Minutes from Date

Tags: php, html, date, format, subtraction

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin') );
$dateUpdate = $date->format("d.m.Y H:i:s");
```

Hey, i need to subtract 4 Minutes from `$dateUpdate`.
How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54878827/5947043 . Same can be found in [many other places](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+datetime+subtract+minutes) - did you search at all?? P.S. $dateUpdate is a string so you can't subtract from that directly, you have to subtract from $date and then format the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$interval = new DateInterval("PT4M");
$date->sub($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
```

[DateTime Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

[DateInterval Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php)