# Decreasing DateInterval not producing result

Tags: php, php-7, dateinterval

Trying to get the last four Sundays, decrementing in a loop starting with the most recent Sunday first.

```
// most recent sunday
$mostRecentSunday = new DateTime('last sunday');

// four Sundays ago
$maxDateAttempt = clone $mostRecentSunday;
$maxDateAttempt->modify('-4 weeks');

// interval of one week (same as 7 days or "P7D")
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1W');

// isn't this supposedly supposed to switch the increasing interval to decreasing?
$dateInterval->invert = 1;

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($mostRecentSunday, $dateInterval, $maxDateAttempt);

foreach ($dateRange as $day) {
    echo $day->format('F j, Y');
}
```

Taking [@hijarian's answer in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350778/negative-dateinterval/8110014#8110014), I thought setting the invert property would solve this, but I cannot get it to work. Then [this comment in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#114188) claims the DatePeriod class isn't even compatible with negative intervals. Anyone have some clarity in the issue? Maybe the PHP docs could use some improvement here.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comment in the PHP docs is only partially correct. Everything I've read and experimented with so far seems to indicate that DatePeriod doesn't work with negative DateIntervals *when using an end date*. Maybe there's some initial check that the minimum is less than the maximum before it does anything, but I'm really not sure why it doesn't work.

However, it *does* work if you use the recurrences [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) rather than setting an end date.

```
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($mostRecentSunday, $dateInterval, 3);
// using 3 rather than 4 because the initial value is one occurrence
```

But you have to create your `DateInterval` like this instead:

```
$dateInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 week');
```

Interestingly enough, that does not create a 7 day interval with invert=1. If you `var_dump($dateInterval)`, you'll see `public 'd' => int -7` and `public 'invert' => int 0`.

---

But technically you don't need DateInterval or DatePeriod to accomplish this.

```
for ($i=0, $date = new DateTime; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo $date->modify('last sunday')->format('F j, Y');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I agree that this is the best alternative. I really wanted to figure out how to properly get the negative intervals to work.

Comment: @TalkNerdyToMe I was only able to figure out one way to make it work with a negative interval, but it's not pretty IMO.

Comment: The invert property is clearly poorly documented. Thank you for your quite comprehensive answer!